# How do I say ' sister languages' in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

El portugues y el castellano son lenguas hermanas porque se origen del latino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another sentence could be:

"El portugués y el castellano son lenguas hermanas porque ambas provienen del latín".

Answer (score 8):

The RAE dictionary says this about "[lenguas hermanas](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=byqNcMf7EDXX2NNLcBVl#lenguas_hermanas.)":

> ~s hermanas.
>   1. f. pl. Las que se derivan de una misma lengua madre; p. ej., el español y el italiano, que se derivan del latín.

So, I think your translation is correct. But I think the last part of the sentence is not very correct. I would say:

> El portugués y el castellano son lenguas hermanas porque se originan en el latín.

or

> El portugués y el castellano son lenguas hermanas porque se derivan del latín.

Please, note the diacritic "e" in "portugués" ;)

Comment: No offense to the other answer, but why wasn't this accepted?  Neither was that one the firs answer nor is the one that the more upvotes has! I mean, the criterion this OP has is random choice.

Comment: @c.p. I've noticed that this user usually choose very random answers, I mean, he often choose answers with no upvotes or even downvoted over other answers with many upvotes which are much better than the ones he's choosing, no entiendo cual es su criterio para seleccionar las respuestas.

Comment: En mi experiencia, este usuario ha aceptado dos de mis respuestas para después cambiarlas por respuestas recientes de 0 votos. Supongo que debe coger la respuesta que más le resulte práctica pero a razón de las opiniones de la mayoría de usuarios (upvotes) no estoy segura de si dejarlo así, avisar a moderación o preguntar en Meta.

Comment: a mi me ha pasado tres veces ya con este usuario. @DerPolyglott33, We've noticed that you change frequently the accepted anwser, why you do that, what are the reasons behind your behavior? Please.

Comment: Just happened to me on Portuguese Language, the very first time he posted a question there. Glad to know I'm not alone.